# Joomla Post/Get/Forward Assistance

Tags: post, joomla

I am using Joomla v1.6 and am need of some assistance. I have aprox. 50 videos with titles that are a numeric value. I want the site's visitors to enter the title number and be immediately forwarded to the appropriate article. Due to the ongoing videos being added, a menu will not work and a search module will display a majority of the videos. Since the user might be watching the incorrect video if a choice is given (search results). I guess what I need is to limit the steps/clicks the visitor has to use to see their video choice.

I have spent the last three weeks looking to no avail. I have two Joomla.org post will no answers.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: How are the videos contained within the website - are they in a folder with the files named number.flv (for example 12345.flv)? How do people see them at the moment - have you embedded one video per article? I think it would be trivial to have a piece of php or even javascript detect the video number and show the appropriate video/article.

Comment: Yes. Embed the videos each in an article [ With something like the AllVideos plugin] and then pattern match the url per my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the video numbers in the title, won't they come up in the URL?

For example, article titled '12345' which I assume contains your video:

```
SEO off: index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1:12345&catid=7:video&Itemid=101

SEO on: /component/content/article/7-video/1-12345
```

idea: You could probably really easily do a form submit using something like [Jumi](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content/1023) and just match the url pattern with a little php, substituting the submitted form video number for the last part of the url.`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use K2 to categorize and manage your videos.
K2 is similar to Joomla's built-in com_content, but has many extra features.

You can download it here:

http://getk2.org/